# Find bound pairs/subsets

Tags: data-mining, algorithms, association-rules

I have 6000 sets of ~350 items each, all from the pool of ~13800 items total. Items in each set do not repeat. I want to find rules like "if 1398 is present, 1035 will most likely be present too". I've tried FPGrowth and Eclat, but the problem is, not every set has these combinations, so their support is low and they're shadowed by more common combinations. Is there any algorithm that accounts for support only if either of the items is present?

Comment: Okay, apparently FPGrowth_association_rules from SPMF does this. Let's see what it will produce...